# Get users from Active Directory group where group name has spaces in between

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am searching for a AD Group "PT Sport Contact Centre Team (India)"

The code is I have used is

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
using System.Text;

namespace GetUserInAGroup
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string groupName = string.Empty;
            string domainName = string.Empty;
            StringBuilder data=new StringBuilder();
            Console.WriteLine("Group Name");
             groupName = "PT Sport Contact Centre Team (India)"; //Console.ReadLine();
             domainName = "ad.MyDomain.com";

            PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName);
            GroupPrincipal grp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.Name, groupName);

            if (grp != null)
            {
                foreach (Principal p in grp.GetMembers(true))
                {
                    data.Append(p.Name + '|' + p.UserPrincipalName + '|' + p.SamAccountName + '|' + groupName + System.Environment.NewLine);
                    //Console.WriteLine(p.Name +'|' + p.UserPrincipalName + '|' + p.SamAccountName); //You can add more attributes, samaccountname, UPN, DN, object type, etc... 
                }

                Console.WriteLine(data.ToString());
                grp.Dispose();
                ctx.Dispose();
                domainName = Console.ReadLine();
                using (StreamWriter outfile =new StreamWriter(@"D:\Temp" + @"\" + groupName + ".txt"))
                {
                    outfile.Write(data.ToString());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nWe did not find that group in that domain, perhaps the group resides in a different domain?");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

May because of the spaces its not able to find the Group or is could be the brackets. Please can someone help.

Comment: Can you confirm that while debugging this code the pointer reaches inside `if(grp!=null)` statement?

Comment: Also, please check the output of this powershell command: `Get-ADGroup -Filter 'Name -eq "PT Sport Contact Centre Team (India)"' | Select *`, and see if it yields any result. If there is no result, it means there is no such group. In that case, can you please share the screenshot of the group?